# Creating a property that is the same for all objects

Tags: c++, linux, class, gpio

How to create a property that will be the same for all objects created by the class. In order to be able to set this property once and all objects created further, already have this property set.

Linux ARM64

```cpp
class gpio {
    public:

    // some object properties
    string board_name;
    int phy_gpio;

    // Default constructor
    gpio() {

    }

    // Parameterized Constructor
    gpio (int phy_pin_num) {
        ...
    }

    // method specifying the board_name property
    void set_board (string board) {
        board_name = board;
    }

    privare:

};
```

The problem is that the gpio port number depends on the model of the board. 
It is necessary to make the board model set once, and then used to create objects of the gpio class.

The name of the board must be set before creating the gpio object, that is, before creating any of the available class objects using any of the available constructors.

Comment: Modern way of handling GPIO is to rely on the chip and pin relative number. In some cases you may find this by using pin name. Consider to use `libgpiod`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you looked the `static` keyword ?
If I understood it right, after you initialize your first GPIO, you can set its model and every other `gpio` should have this same value.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class gpio {
   public:

   static string board_model;
   gpio() {}
   ~gpio() {}
   string returnModel() {return board_model}
};

string gpio::board_model = "none";

int main()  {

    gpio pin;
    std::cout << pin.returnModel() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.I added a description of the problem. The name of the board must be set before creating the gpio object, that is, before creating any of the available class objects using any of the available constructors.

Comment: You can set the value of a static-member-variable before creating any objects of the class (just make sure the setter-method is also tagged with the `static` keyword, so that you can call e.g. `gpio::set_board("blah")` at the beginning of your program)

Comment: It does not seem to work, or am I mistaken somewhere? http://cpp.sh/6wt42

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question clearly, final keyword will solve your issue. If you use:

```
final string board_name = "Some Value"
```

The value for the board_name will be same for all the instance of the gpio class.

Comment: final -> const. final keyword in c++ has a different purpose, to prevent virt functions being overridden in derived classes.

Comment: Yes, I know. It could also be usable for this purpose.

Comment: it won't compile.

Comment: I must define this property in class? And How can i specify this property before creating object? can you give an example?